# Disable Autodiscover in Outlook

Tags: exchange, outlook, outlook-2007

My Dad's Outlook constantly asks him for Autodiscover settings. Since he is using 1and1 and I'm hosting the domain and doing email forwarding, I'd like to disable the Autodiscover process on his PC. How do I do that?

This is specifically the Exchange HTTPS Autodiscover process for Cached Exchange on Outlook 2007.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't disable Autodiscover. Outlook uses it at launch to locate the mailbox server for a given user, but it also runs periodically while Outlook is open so that it will notice changes to a user's mailbox.

Please Check: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124251%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was adding exchange_server_name.domain.local to the bypass proxy setting on the client machine.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used these instructions before, but they strike me as a potentially legitimate solution. Unfortunately I don't have an appropriate machine to test out this problem on at the moment.

http://windowsitpro.com/article/articleid/96913/how-can-i-force-my-microsoft-outlook-2007-client-to-a-particular-autodiscovery-server.html

Comment: Saw that one when I added my entry. It doesn't disable autodiscovery, as the title says, it forces the client to a particular autodiscovery server.

Comment: fair point. I also saw the article below, so I think this is a lost cause, but hoped this might provide a work around in a way that I don't fully understand =)

Answer (score 0):

It can't be disabled that I know of. A Microsoft employee [wrote on TechNet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exchangesvrclients/thread/2ccb0f7e-971b-4c71-88a4-360e94e275bb/) that disabling it was not possible (see Xiu Zhang answers). Will continue researching and post back findings.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the autodiscovery domain in my hosts file worked for me.

Put the following in your hosts file:

```
127.0.0.2    autodiscover.<domainname>.com
```

The hosts file is located in **C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc**.

Comment: line does not show correctly -

Comment: "127.0.0.2       autodiscover.YOURDOMAIN NAME.com"

Answer (score 0):

On Outlook 2007 my fix was to go to credential manager and delete the referenced credentials for autodiscover.myserver.net.

Answer (score 0):

This autodiscover nag dialog is very annoying - maybe 5 times in one minute. It has a very frustrating checkbox which says "don't ask me again", but checking it doesn't work unless you select "allow"